# Add YAAF to the Microsoft Visual C++ search directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am completely new to working on MS Visual Studio.
I am trying to install new framework where in the installation guide tells me

"Add YAAF to the Microsoft Visual C++ search directories"
YAAF i suppose is the directory over here that i have got.

But does not mention how do i do it.
Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's the same as VS2008, it can be found in:

Tools~Options~Visual C++ Directories

Use the droplist in the top right and select Include Files (or Library files, whatever you need for your framework).